# How pass a value from javascript to objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I've a great problem. I must pass a variable of a javascript function into an objective-C variable. 
These are my code's parts:

Javascript:

```
function abc(){
something...
}
```

Objective-C:

```
    myLabel.text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"documentElement.textContent"];
```

The javascript code prints to video a number that I want use in my Objective-C code but with this nothing appears, instead using this code:

```
myLabel.text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
```

It pass the value that I want and the entire code of the javascript function!

Please some advice.... Thanks at all!!!

`

Comment: I guess you need a javascript runtime to embed into the Objective C application...

Comment: @fortran: The WebView has JavaScript functionality, hence the function he's calling.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh, I thought that "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" function was some kind of placeholder name for a real function!!! I couldn't believe such a long name existed ^_^

Comment: @fortran: Yeah, it's a doozy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wan to *call* the function, not just refer to it:

```
myLabel.text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent()"];
```

the key bit is at the end:

```
...documentElement.textContent()"];
//                            ^^
```

Since JavaScript functions are first-class objects, when you do:

```
x = functionName;
```

...`x` receives a reference to the function. In your case, since the UIWebView then coerces it to a string, you end up calling `toString` on the function, which on most JavaScript implementations gives you the code of the function (although this is not specified by any standard).

To actually *call* a function, you put parentheses after it (with nothing in them, if there are no arguments you need to pass; or with arguments in them if you do), e.g.:

```
x = functionName();
```

Disclosure: I know nothing about iOS development, Objective-C, or `UIWebView`, but I was able to quickly find the [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) function you were using, and then confirmed via [this page](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview) that the string after the `@` needs to be valid JavaScript code.