# Pass variable from JavaScript to Objective-C - JSON?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How pass a value from javascript to objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216315/how-pass-a-value-from-javascript-to-objective-c)

I want to pass a text variable from JavaScript to an Objective-C variable.

My HTML file looks like this:

```html
<p>Bitte tragen Sie die Document ID ein:</p>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    function testResults(form){
        location.href = DocumentID.value;
    }
</SCRIPT>

<form action="">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Document ID:</td>
      <td><input name="DocumentID" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" value="35060e6242160705744ffd8e280005b9"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="right">Formular:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" NAME ="button" value=" Absenden " onClick="testResults(this.form)">
        <input type="reset" value=" Abbrechen">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

This is the Objective-C code:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {


    if([request.URL.relativeString isEqualToString:@"http://localhost:8888/"])
    //if([request.URL.relativeString rangeOfString:@"http://localhost:8888/"].location)
    {
        //self.URL
        [self loadData];

        return true;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Can somebody give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: based on which native event you want to fire javascript event?...

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, make it so that the form submission sets a variable in javascript and then loads a dummy url.

You capture that url in Obj-C like you have done above and then call a function in javascript to return the variable.

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myfunc('%@')", html];
NSString *result = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

So myfunc in javascript returns the form variable.