# How do I pass a variable from javascript to c?

Tags: javascript, c

I am trying to pass a variable for a timer between a webpage that runs online to a device that is connected to the internet that is able to have the timer be displayed on the device and count down. The device is programmed in c and the variables from the webpage are in javascript. I have very little experience with c, so I am sorry if this is basic stuff. This answer seemed to only address the problem for objective-c and I am hoping to solve it for c: [How pass a value from javascript to objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216315/how-pass-a-value-from-javascript-to-objective-c) 
Thanks again for helping.

Comment: If that is JS and **Objective-** C, why add the **C**-tag?